# API id - Convert ids into integer

Tags: python, encoding, converters

I'm playing with API and it throw me this kind of id : ff869d1f-0923-4d28-8577-4c36291f0fca

I wonder if the id is encoded in a specific format and if I can convert it into an integer, working on python.

Comment: technically you could since its hexadecimal but it is not an integer its a uuid

Answer (score 0):

Your ID is a UUID. Technically it is a 128bit integer, but since such long numbers are rather impractical to use they are mostly presented as dash-separated hexadecimal groups like your `ff869d1f-0923-4d28-8577-4c36291f0fca`.

Python as well as modern databases offer direct support for UUIDs. In most cases it is not helpful to convert them.

Exact details about UUIDs, their types (versions), fields and conversion options can be found in the [documentation of the UUID module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html).